# Laravel finally callback not always called on batched jobs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Using Laravel 8, it seems as in several cases (Which currently seem to be sporadic), `finally` callback of `Bus::batch` does not get called

Using like this:

```
Bus::batch($jobs)
  ->onQueue('queue_name')
  ->name(Job::class)
  ->allowFailures()
  ->catch(function () {
    logger()->error("Job failed");
  })
  ->finally(function () use ($feed) {
    logger("Jobs done);
  })
  ->dispatch();
```

Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't `finally` always be called no matter what happens? How can I make sure of that?

Comment: Are all of your jobs finished? After the last job is finished, the finally method is called. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-batches

Comment: @Dennis It seems as there are jobs that just don't report success/pending/failure, just lost, although I see the task at least starting. And in this scenario, indeed finally is not called.

Comment: If you set the QUEUE_CONNECTION to sync in your .env file. Maybe you see some errors popping up, or keep hanging. You should debug the code in your job to determine what is causing this behaviour. Maybe you can put also your job in the question, so we can inspect it.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more on QUEUE_CONNECTION sync? We're using Redis, and I do see the job object serialized, together with the correct batch id, but looking at the batch it's missing

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use this traits for you EventClass

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Batchable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;  
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class NameEvent implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, Batchable, Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue;
     
}
```